# Моделирование данных в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, случайные-числа

Я начал изучать тему: Метод статистических тестов и наткнулся на такую проблему: В мусорный бак может поместиться 10 пакетов с мусором.
В день в бак с равной вероятностью может поступить 0, 1, 2 или 3 пакета. Построить модель поступления пакетов в бак. На основании 1000 испытаний оценить математическое ожидание числа дней до полного заполнения бака Параметр датчика случайных чисел установлен на 0,1,2,3 и пришел к такому решению:  `10/mean(random.choices([0,1,2,3], k=10000))`, но оно не работает. Почему?

Comment: Да не мудрите, делайте всë в циклах. Внешний цикл на 1000 испытаний, во внутреннем генерируются случайные числа, пока их сумма не заполнит бак. Считайте количества дней, ищите среднее.

Comment: Вы научились использовать numpy, но не можете цикл написать? https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/2.7.php

Comment: @КириллМалышев  `import random  n=int(input())                                                                                                                    l=[random.randrange(1000)]                                                                                                                 for i in range(1000):                                                                                                                                for i in range(n)`: так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random
s = 0
for _ in range(1000):
    p = 0
    days = 0
    while p < 10:
        p += random.randint(0, 3)
        days += 1
    s += days
print(s / 1000)
```